# Ruby on rails cant modify frozen ActiveRecord::LazyAttributeHash when deleting database entries

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, rails-activerecord

When I delete something via http request in my Rails API I get the error "Runtime Error in InputsController#destroy cant modify frozen ActiveRecord::LazyAttributeHash". The strange thing is that the database entries that I am targeted are actually deleted but it cannot render the json response. Does anyone know why this error is and how to resolve it? thanks.

Here is my controller.

```
class InputsController < ApplicationController
   def index
     @inputs = Input.all
      render json: @inputs, :include => [:descriptions, :ratings, :flags]
   end

   def show
    @input = find_specific_input

    if @input
      render json: @input, status: :created, location: @input
    else
      render json: @input.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def create
    @input = Input.create(allowed_params)

     if @input.save
      render json: @input, status: :created, location: @input
    else
      render json: @input.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def update
    @input = find_specific_input

    if @input.update(allowed_params)
      render json: @input, status: :created, location: @input
    else
      render json: @input.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @input = find_specific_input

    if @input.destroy
      render json: @input, status: :created, location: @input
    else
       render json: @input.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
    end
  end


  private

  def allowed_params
    params.require(:input).permit(:category, :longitude, :latitude, :user_id, :mountain_id)
  end

  def find_specific_input
    Input.find(params[:id])
  end
end
```

I am using the gems:

```
gem 'rails', '4.2.0.rc2'
gem 'rails-api'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def destroy
  input = find_specific_input
  destroyed_input = input.as_json # or try .to_json

  if input.destroy
    render json: destroyed_input, status: :created, location: destroyed_input
  else
    render json: input.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity
  end
end
```

BTW this is probably the same bug reported [here](https://github.com/jrhe/grape-active_model_serializers/issues/32).

Comment: I tried this and got the same error, any more thoughts?